# Bash getopts does not recognize parameter

Tags: bash, shell

```
while getopts ":hufc:p:i" opt; do

  case $opt in
    h)
        usage
        exit 1
        ;;
    u)
      DOUPDATE=false
      ;;
    f)
      DOCONFIRMATION=false
      ;;
    c)
       CUSTOMERTYPE=$OPTARG
       ;;
    p)
       CUSTOMERPROFILE=$OPTARG
       ;;
    i)
        echo "LOL $INSTALL"
        INSTALL=true
        ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
     :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Above is my bash code. When I try to use "i" as a parameter in the command line, case i is not entered.

What should I do?

Comment: Works fine for me. Copied this exact code into `foo.sh`, then ran `sh foo.sh -i` and it prints `LOL`.

Comment: This should work, are you using `-i`? or just `i`, like this: `./myScript i`? You must use `-i` like this: `./myScript -i`.

Comment: I don't understand because, in my terminal same using -i or i don't printing "LOOL".

Comment: In new release, copy only this code and worked, but in my program don't.

Comment: Then the question is, what is your program doing before it gets to this loop?

Answer (score 0):

If your command line has any invalid options prior to the i, it won't parse any farther than the error. If your command line has a -c or -p without a subsequent argument to go into CustomerType or CustomerProfile, it will not parse any farther.

```
#Examples that should work
script.sh -i
script.sh -c customerX -p profileX -i
script.sh -iz

#Examples that will not work
script.sh -hi   #-h option will exit before it parses -i
script.sh -zi   #invalid option z will exit
script.sh -c customerX -p -i #Missing required argument after -p
```